# My hero image isn't appearing, but the text is

Tags: html, css

My hero image isn't appearing, but the text is. All my files are in the same folder and I'm using the relative path VS Code gave me.

This is the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="hero-image">
  <div class="hero-text">
    <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am Matthew Moyes</h1>
    <h3>And I'm a Motivational Speaker</h3>
    <button>BOOK ME</button>
  </div>
</div>
<h3>Page content..</h3>
<p>Note that this technique will also make the image responsive: Resize the browser window to see the effect.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hero-image {
  background: url("/city.jpg");
  background-color:#cccccc;
  height: 500px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.hero-text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}
h3 {
  text-align:center;
}
p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

The part I'm having issues with is the `.hero-image` tag.

I tried putting it in another folder and making a new path as well as re-downloading the image. I also added and removed dots and slashes in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Remove slash from your path like this:

```
background: url("city.jpg");
```

And not like this:

```
background: url("/city.jpg");
```

Comment: I have, unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: If you really have the image in the same folder it should work. You can try to clear your browser's cache. Maybe that is the issue.

Comment: idk, it still isn't working, even when i use it with an image tag

Comment: I actually tried @Vladimir's answer and it worked. So maybe you should check other things like file names and extensions.